# Industry Insights on Client JRE 1.11 upgrade

Tags: java, applet, upgrade

I would like to know if there are any industry benchmarks for client JRE 1.11 upgrade (i.e. what other organizations are doing for the managing the upgrade to java 11). Since, Applets and Java Web Start are not supported by Java 11, applications that are based on these technologies will be affected. I would like to know insights around the planned upgrade.
This should be a universal problem across organizations. If you have any specific information with respect to your organizations, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Beyond 'Rework applets and JWS apps into either desktop apps (distributed another way) or pure web apps' I'm not sure what you expect to hear, but it'd likely be off topic.

Comment: This site was built to avoid open-ended long-winded discussions. So your Question, while interesting, is not on-topic here. Try a discussion/forum site such as http://www.JavaRanch.com/. Tip: Read [*Java Is Still Free*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53112096/642706), a white paper written by key members of the Java community. FYI, no more JRE as a separate distribution. Search to learn about the *Java Platform Module System*, *jlink*, and *jpackage* if you are trying to ship a desktop or mobile app.