# Where is JRE 11?

Tags: java, java-11

## UPDATE:

<sup>*(to be **more clear**)*</sup>

You can find [JRE 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html), [JRE 9](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase9-3934878.html) and [JRE 10](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase10-4425482.html) on Oracle's official website (click on each). *But where is **JRE 11**?!*

Also, JDK 11 doesn't include a JRE. I was expecting JRE to be installed with JDK.

***Do final users of our apps need to install JDK?***

---

## ORIGINAL version of the question:

I downloaded and installed Oracle JDK 11 from its [official site](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html). I installed both  `..._linux-x64_bin.rpm` and `..._windows-x64_bin.exe` (first on a Linux machine and second on a Windows machine). But I saw an unexpected thing! Where is JRE?

This is a snapshot of installation path on CentOS 7. As you can see there is no `jre` folder:

```
# ls /usr/java/jdk-11.0.1/
bin  conf  include  jmods  legal  lib  README.html  release
```

Same snapshot about Oracle JDK 8 (See `jre` folder specially):

```
# ls /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_191-amd64/
bin             lib          src.zip
COPYRIGHT       LICENSE      THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
include         man          THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
javafx-src.zip  README.html
jre             release
```

---

Same snapshots on Windows machine:

```
> dir /b "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1" 
bin                                           
conf                                          
COPYRIGHT                                     
include                                       
jmods                                         
legal                                         
lib                                           
README.html                                   
release                                                                                     
           
> dir /b "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181"  
bin                                           
COPYRIGHT                                     
include                                       
javafx-src.zip                                
jre                                           
lib                                           
LICENSE                                       
README.html                                   
release                                       
src.zip                                       
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt            
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
```

---

On Windows machine, there are also two another differences between JDK 8 and JDK 11.

1. A standalone `JRE` alongside `JDK` as you can see:

   ```
   > dir /b "C:\Program Files\Java"            
   jdk-11.0.1   
   jdk1.8.0_181 
   jre1.8.0_181
   ```
2. In path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java`:

   ```
   > dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java"                                                                   
   ...                                                                                                                   
   ...                14 java.settings.cfg                                                                  
   ...    <JUNCTION>     javapath [C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath_target_3015921] 
   ...    <DIR>          javapath_target_3015921 
   ...
   ```

   As you see `javapath` (that is in `PATH` environment variable) points to `javapath_target_3015921`. This folder contains 3 executables of JDK 8 (that aren't *link*s!):

   ```
   > dir /b "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath" 
   java.exe                         
   javaw.exe                        
   javaws.exe
   ```

---

Finally, I searched the web to find a standalone JRE and found out it doesn't exist!

***Do final users of our programs need to install JDK?***

Comment: You might be further surprised to know that the Oracle JDK isn't free anymore except for development/testing purposes. Better switch to OpenJDK.

Comment: @rustyx - Thanks for reminding this important note!

Comment: On the upside though OpenJDK does about everything OracleJDK does. If you can come up with things that you can't do with OpenJDK. I'd be interested. JavaFX was one of the things you needed OracleJDK before. Now it's completely seperate from any JDK/JRE and you bundle it with your program with a built tool like maven or gradle.

Comment: There are at least 9 sources for obtaining an implementation of Java 11. Some are free-of-cost and some are not. See my flowchart diagram listing these sources on [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54737381/642706) to the original of this duplicate Question.

Comment: Taking up @rustyx's helpful remark. The link to OpenJDK's JRE is [here](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html)

Comment: I like getting my OpenJDK builds from [**ojdkbuild**](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/releases) project. And for development I'm using [**DCEVM**](http://dcevm.github.io/), which allows updating class definitions without a VM restart, so is like jrebel but free.

Comment: Till which version Oracle JDK was allowed for commercial use? I thought from starting it is only allowed for development & teasting

Comment: @SatishPatro Oracle has used different licensing terms for different versions of their *Oracle JDK* product. One license required a fee for deployment, another requires a fee when bundling the JDK within your app. Be sure to read the license carefully for any JDK you obtain. Also, you have a choice of other JDK vendors, each with their own terms: Azul Systems, Microsoft, Amazon, Bellsoft, Adoptium, SAP, Red Hat, IBM, and more.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The whole structure with Java 11 has changed. Java is now a modular platform, where you can create your own "JRE" distribution with specifically the modules that you need to run your application.

The release notes at https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html have the following sentence:

> In this release, the JRE or Server JRE is no longer offered. Only the
>   JDK is offered. Users can use jlink to create smaller custom runtimes.

Documentation about jlink: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jlink.html

And another article about it: https://medium.com/codefx-weekly/is-jlink-the-future-1d8cb45f6306

Comment: OMG..... what theee.....

Comment: But if your app uses jars which are not modular, `jlink` breaks because it only works with modern, modular jars. It doesn't work with 'automatic jars' which are created from older non modular jars being put onto the --module-path, either.  Thankfully it looks like you can download open JRE from https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/

Comment: The JRE link is dead

Comment: @J'e  As of 2023-08, several companies offer JRE products. These include [Azul Systems](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-20-sts&package=jre#zulu), [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?package=jre&version=20), and more. Check Amazon, BellSoft, Microsoft, Oracle, SAP, Red Hat, IBM, and others. –

Comment: The link provided "https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html" is broken: "But the page you were looking for is still missing."