# How To Download JDK 1.8.0_191

Tags: java, java-8, pdfbox, pdfrenderer

I'm trying to use `PDFRenderer` from `PDFBox` and works fine but it gives me a warning saying:

```
Aug 31, 2019 11:46:48 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS
INFO: Your current java version is: 1.8.0_171
Aug 31, 2019 11:46:48 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS
INFO: To get higher rendering speed on old java 1.8 or 9 versions,
Aug 31, 2019 11:46:48 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS
INFO:   update to the latest 1.8 or 9 version (>= 1.8.0_191 or >= 9.0.4),
Aug 31, 2019 11:46:48 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS
INFO:   or
Aug 31, 2019 11:46:48 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS
INFO:   use the option -Dsun.java2d.cmm=sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider
Aug 31, 2019 11:46:48 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS
INFO:   or call System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider")
```

which from what i understand it means i have to update to JDK 1.8.0_191 or higher to get the best experience out of the object.

my problem here is that how can I get the 1.8.0_191 or higher version of the JDK or any other solutions to implement, so that I won't get this warning and the `PDFRenderer` works faster.

Comment: @BasilBourque yea i just found out and fixed it, thanks anyways

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Stewardship

Be aware that Oracle stopped providing free-of-cost security updates to [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8). See [*Oracle Java SE Support Roadmap*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-se-support-roadmap.html).

[Red Hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat) (IBM) has [taken stewardship](https://www.theserverside.com/news/252461945/Red-Hat-replaces-Oracle-as-OpenJDK-8-OpenJDK-11-steward) of the OpenJDK 8 & OpenJDK 11 [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) releases.

## Oracle branded

Oracle JDK 8 Update 221 is available [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). Be sure to read the terms of the license, and be aware of their intention towards further updates.

## OpenJDK

The open-source distributions based on [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) are available from various vendors.

The first that comes to mind is [AdoptOpenJDK.net](https://adoptopenjdk.net), providing Java 8 with Update 282 currently.

Amazon provides [OpenJDK 8](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html) in their [Corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/) offering. Especially suitable if you deploy to [AWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services).

[Zulu by Azul Systems](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-community/) also provides [OpenJDK 8](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&version=java-8-lts), [certified as Java](https://assets.azul.com/files/Zulu-Enterprise-Data-Sheet-v5-15-19.pdf). They offer optional support plans as well.

See the [nifty diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54737381/642706) I made for sourcing Java 11. Some of those same vendors also provide Java 8, with and without paid support.

Comment: yeah just realized everything right now, thanks for helping anyways i,ll mark that as an answer as soon as possible