# Java JDK, JRE, JVM

Tags: java

I was trying to update my jave version and got confused a little bit. I have jdk 10, which I used, and also have Java Platform 8, which have "configure java" app, so what should I do now, if you go to java.com they're offering you to install java 8 only, do I need to delete old java 8 and jdk 10 and then install jdk 11 from oracle.com? Does it have jre in it? Can I run for example apps like Minecraft if I do that and write code too? Also what should I install: oracle jdk or open jdk then?

Comment: Get it from here https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

Comment: I know the link, it's not my question

Comment: Jdk has jre you'll find java.exe here `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin`. I think you can use Oracle JDK for personal use. If you want to keep both new and old JDKs then update JAVA_HOME, CLASSPATH environment variables with new locations.

Comment: In your Mincraft launcher set java.exe path to new location. The game should work with latest java versions. `As of the Java Edition 1.12 update, Minecraft requires Java 8 or newer`  https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Update_Java#:~:text=As%20of%20the%20Java%20Edition,relatively%20modern%20version%20of%20Java

Comment: @onkarruikar There are many vendors from which to get an implementation of Java. Some are free-of-cost and some are commercial. The one you linked is commercial in that in requires a payment for use in production.

Comment: @BasilBourque agreed!  I think for playing Minecraft it should be ok. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java JDK is Java Development Kit, which installs everything you need to write, compile, and run Java code and programs. It includes the Java JRE, which is the Java Runtime Environment. It only has what you need to run Java apps/programs. The download you're being offered when you go to java.com is the JRE. The JVM is the Java Virtual Machine, which is the engine for running Java programs and comes with both the JRE and JDK.

If you're looking to run and develop Java programs, all you need to do is install the JDK. I would suggest uninstalling any previous versions of Java you have for security reasons, as support could've been dropped for them. As for OpenJDK and Oracle JDK, OpenJDK is the open source implementation of Java, and other JDKs like Oracles are built on top of it. The OpenJDK does not require a license to use while others might, depending on your use case.

Comment: However, note that since Java 9, you won't find JRE (only) downloads on either the Oracle Java or OpenJDK Java download sites.  It is JDKs for everything ... unless you go for a 3rd-party vendor.

Comment: OpenJDK provides only source code, not builds or installers. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54737381/642706) on other Question for help in choosing any of several vendors providing builds & installers.